# How to save sensors' data on react native firebase (accelerometer and gyroscope)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, accelerometer, gyroscope

All i need is to save the data from sensors to a database. The example of the sensors i found in documentation page (i.e., https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/accelerometer/ and https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/gyroscope/ are fine and work for me. What I need is to save those data in real time on a database in order to process them. Any help even tutorial provided except from documentation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To connect your application with firebase, follow these steps:

- Create a firebase account.
- Create a project and add your android/ios application to your
  project.
- Install react-native-firebase npm package in your rn
  application.

Then you will file some queries and methods defined in firebase documentation.
Use that to store and fetch your sensor values.

guide:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlZ5da62b74

Firebase's real-time database is the product you can use to store and read the sensor values.